Cannot assign to read only property using RECOIL
This is the code where I am defining my atoms,
import { io } from "socket.io-client"; import { atom, useRecoilState } from 'recoil';

export const count = atom({
    key: 'count',
    default: 0 });


export const socketConnectionState = atom({
    key: 'socketConnectionState',
    default: io('https://localhost:8001') });

This is causing error
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_callbacks' of object '#<_Request>'

I want to use recoil for this as I want to use this same socket in different files so making new ones causes irregularities.
Help me find a fix.
